# Get record from integer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

`<%= @duel.duelers.where.not(user_id: current_user.id).first.user_id %>` produces an integer, i.e. `1`, but how can I get it to produce the record from that user_id `#<User:0x007fe476a42948>`?

Comment: What record do you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the last user_id with the record you want to show.

e.g.

```
<%= @duel.duelers.where.not(user_id: current_user.id).first.user_id %>
```

to (for all records)

```
<%= @duel.duelers.where.not(user_id: current_user.id).first.user %>
```

or for a single record:

```
<%= @duel.duelers.where.not(user_id: current_user.id).first.user_name %>
```

This part; `@duel.duelers.where.not(user_id: current_user.id).first` already got you on the user so anything you put behind that will display the record for that instance.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to retrieve the `user` object, you can do

`@duel.duelers.where.not(user_id: current_user.id).first.user`

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `user` on first `duel` instead of `user_id` make sure you have the following association

```
duel has_one :user
```

and then

```
<%= @duel.duelers.where.not(user_id: current_user.id).first.user %>
```